# How to find the non matching records between two files using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

file1

```
1|footbal|play1
2|cricket1|play2
3|golf|play3
4|tennis|play4
5|bowling|play5
```

file 2

```
1|footbal|play1
2|cricket|play2
4|tennis|play4
```

i am comparing file2 with file1 and output should be

```
3|golf|play3
5|bowling|play5
```

i need only records which are not present in file2 and should be in file1.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {exclude[$0];next} !($0 in exclude)' file2.txt file1.txt
```

This is not giving expected result.

Comment: Please edit your question and wrap your samples in code tags as per forum rules.

Comment: If your files are sorted, then just `comm -23` I think.

Comment: This might help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9918/printing-unique-lines

Comment: You have `2|cricket1|play2` int file1 and `2|cricket|play2` in file2 -- it that intentional?/ A simple way is `grep -F -v -f file2 file1`

Comment: @rakeshkandukuri, Rakesh, you didn't answer mine and David's questions, how program will know you are considering cricket and cricket1 as same ? I have deleted my answer until this question is clear.

Comment: `sort file1 file2 file2 | uniq -u`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `grep` may give wrong output if lines in file2 can be substrings of lines in file1 (eg. consider if file1 contains `1|footbal|play123`)

Comment: Good point, you can add `-w` for whole words, e.g. `grep -F -v -w -f file2 file1`

Comment: `grep -F -v -x -f file2 file1` is posix and should work for any line-delimited records, not just ones comprising a single word

Comment: "This is not giving expected result." What is the expected result?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  i understood your question but am just asking is there anyway i can get the expected output through awk command. if it is not possible i will check other alternative solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Trying one more time to get OP's expected output by making first field as index key.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
}
NR==FNR{
  exclude[$1]
  next
}
!($1 in exclude)
' file2.txt file1.txt
```

---

---

Your code looks good, could you please try following there may be a have if control M characters in your samples. Try removing them before processing them.

```
awk '{gsub(/\r|[[:space:]]+$/,"")} NR==FNR {exclude[$0];next} !($0 in exclude)' file2.txt file1.txt
```

I am also removing the space from last of the lines incase you have any.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use awk, but [`comm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/comm.1.html) is purpose-built to print out commonalities and differences between two files:

```
$ comm -23 file1.txt file2.txt
3|golf|play3
5|bowling|play5
```

(I assume the `cricket1` in your sample file1 is a typo, given your expected output).

The catch is that the files have to be sorted in lexicographic order, while based on your sample, yours are sorted numerically based on the first column, which is different once you have a 10 or higher. So, a minor change might be needed (Requires `bash`, `zsh`, or another shell that understands `<(command)` syntax:

```
comm -23 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

`comm` takes three important arguments - `-1`, which suppresses lines only present in the first file, `-2`, which suppresses lines only present in the second file, and `-3`, which suppresses lines present in both files. So `-23` ends up printing only lines that are unique to the first file. `-13` would print lines that are unique to the second file.